# What is the point of training in the corral?

Tags: secret-of-the-magic-crystals

In "Secret of the Magic Crystals", I can train my magical horse in the corral, but I don't understand the point of this training: there is no feedback to the player. Does the training affect the statistics of the horse?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The horse starts with all stats (Strength, Speed, Stamina, Dexterity, Reflex) equal to zero. By training, the horse will be able to max its stats to the max value (default: 100).

The Intelligence stat is not affected by training. It is determined by the amount of care you give to the horse when it was a child.